# How to extract text from docx file with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mammoth

i want to extract text from docx file, i have tried using mammoth

```
var mammoth = require("mammoth");
mammoth.extractRawText({path: "./doc.docx"})
    .then(function(result){
        var text = result.value; // The raw text 

        //this prints all the data of docx file
        console.log(text);

        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            //this prints all the data char by char in separate lines
            console.log(text[i]);
        }
        var messages = result.messages;
    })
    .done();
```

but the problem here is that in this for loop i want data line by line instead of char by char, please help me here or is there any other method that you know?

Comment: What do you mean line by line? Like individual lines of the word document, or paragraphs separated by newlines?

Comment: like individual lines of the document @ExplosionPills

Comment: One way is splitting your text by "\n"s !

Comment: did you run this code, in console it is printing char by char data in new lines. there is no need to split by "\n". @tashakori

Comment: No! You got it wrong:-). I mean splitting the text itself by "\n" characters. And then you have an array of lines! Var lines = text.split ("\n"). Then lines [i] indicates the i'th line of text.

Comment: thanks, that helped me. @tashakori

Answer (score 3):

One method is to fetch the whole text and then split by `'\n'`:

```
import superagent from 'superagent';
import mammoth from 'mammoth';

const url = 'http://www.ojk.ee/sites/default/files/respondus-docx-sample-file_0.docx';

const main = async () => {

  const response = await superagent.get(url)
    .parse(superagent.parse.image)
    .buffer();

  const buffer = response.body;

  const text = (await mammoth.extractRawText({ buffer })).value;
  const lines = text.split('\n');

  console.log(lines);
};

main().catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [any-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/any-text)

Usage is simeple:

```js
var reader = require('any-text');

reader.getText(`path-to-file`).then(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var mammoth = require("mammoth");
var path = require("path");

var filePath = path.join(__dirname,'./doc.docx');

mammoth.extractRawText({path: filePath})
    .then(function(result){
        var text = result.value; // The raw text

        //this prints all the data of docx file
        //console.log(text);
        console.log('------------------------------');
        var textLines = text.split ("\n");

        for (var i = 0; i < textLines.length; i++) {
            //this prints all the data in separate lines
            console.log(textLines[i]);
        }
        var messages = result.messages;
    })
    .done();
```