# can't read .docx file after uploading (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to upload and read a .docx file to an express server using `express-fileupload` package. The upload part is working fine but somehow I'm not able to read the file as it prints unreadable gibberish text. Following is the code:

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res, next) => {
  let file = req.files.file;

  file.mv(`${__dirname}/public/${req.body.filename}`, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }

    fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/public/${req.body.filename}`, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log(data) // prints broken text/gibberish;
    });

    res.json({data to be returned});
  });

});
```

What I want is to be able to read the .docx file and do operations on the text inside it.

Comment: what are you expecting to see?  docx is a binary format

Comment: I want to extract the text inside the file.

Comment: I wonder what'd happen if I uploaded a file with an name such as `../../something.evil` O:)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44953008/how-to-extract-text-from-docx-file-with-nodejs

Answer (score 3):

docx file don't contain human-readable text. They are actually ZIP files containing many different XML files - but even the text content of the XML files won't be easy to work with.

If you want to read or even modify text inside a docx file you need to find a library that can read/write the format.

Comment: ```mammoth``` library did the job.